# Extract a part of names before the start of a patern in linux?

Tags: linux

I can list all files ls *.nc

```
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk_abc_195101-196012.nc
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk_abc_198101-196012.nc
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk_bbb_198101-196012.nc
 LM_lkm_kjjkk_abc_196101-196012.nc
 kjkh_lkm_kjjkk_abc_196101-196012.nc
 SAM_lkm_abc_196101-196012.nc
 kjk_lkm_abc_196101-196012.nc
```

However, I need to extract the parts before _abc ? if more than one, just ignore

The answer below will give:

```
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk_bbb_198101-196012.nc
 LM_lkm_kjjkk
 kjkh_lkm_kjjkk
 SAM_lkm
 kjk_lkm
```

I need that names that do not includ abc to not appear in the output:
desired output:

```
 kjkh_lkm_kkkkk
 LM_lkm_kjjkk
 kjkh_lkm_kjjkk
 SAM_lkm
 kjk_lkm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
ls *.nc|sed -E 's/(_abc|_bbb).*//'|sort|uniq > newfile
```

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: The `/g` option is useless because the pattern cannot match more than once per line.

Comment: Redirect to a file with `> filename`. Please search before asking.

Comment: I just noticed that if there is a file with a name that does not include abc , this name is returned as is. So how to exclude from the output those do not include abc?

Comment: now you are changing the initial question... The answer is that you can use `regex` to catch not only `_abc` but other patterns as well..

Comment: Sorry I am not changing. see my update in the question to explain my point, please.